# RTSP vs HLS stream ... which one will play smoothly on an android device

Tags: android, rtsp, http-live-streaming, android-video-player

I am working on an Android application that is aimed at Tablets only. The min required api level is 3.1. The app will be streaming some live tv channels.

I have tested both RTSP & HLS and both run well. However HLS does not seem to work better and **VideoView**'s **onCompletion** is called which should not be called as the stream is from live TV which is not yet completed.

I have RTSP & HLS streams urls of each TV channel. I know Android Android 3.0+ supports HLS but i can also play RTSP.

Which one is better than the other and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RTSP is only supported over UDP. So if your clients are over the internet where there can be packet loss, it's not a good option. But for a local network it's fine.

HLS has pretty weak support in Android, and they seem to break it in a new way with every release. That said, it's probably what you need to use if you're wanting video over the internet. There are some 3rd party libraries available (vitamio and nextreaming) that can allow a more consistent experience across multiple devices and Android versions.

Comment: thanks for the detail... but i dont understand one thing .. how can a 3rd party library stream well if its not properly supported yb the underlying OS such as u said that _"HLS has pretty weak support in Android"_ then how can nextreaming or vitamio make it better??

Comment: AND i searched for _vitamio_ and _nextreaming_ ... i think _vitamio_ is free to download as its jar file was available ..i will test it tomorrow .. _nextreaming_ seems better as i watched its demo video on youtube but i could not find _nextreaming_'s jar library to be integrated into my app ... is it freely available? or at least a "demo" jar library can be found? so i can show this to my company management... thanks

Comment: @AamirHabib I don't think Nextreaming as anything freely available. The third party libraries can use the underlying media frameworks via NDK, but I'm not entirely sure how they do work.

Comment: The best option for HLS would be ExoPlayer https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/, wich is an open source project supported by Google and used for Youtube

Answer (score 0):

I tested NexStreaming and it's pretty good. I would say better than Vitamio. But it's not free. You can request a trial SDK via their website. The SDK has some .jar you can access from an Android app, as well as some native (.so) libs where the decoding happens (I guess).